# How to clean up all environment variable from a respective env. in postman/newman

Tags: postman, newman

I have written tests in postman.

Now I want to clean up all env variable once my script complete.

I do not want to clear them one by one using the below command:

```
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("key");
```

Is there any command who will clear all my env variable keys as a clean up process without deleting my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have a look [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) and try with `pm.globals.clear()` or `pm.environment.clear()`

hope this helps